# Zend_Form - isPost() returns false

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I want to write small register form.
This is my form code:

```
class Application_Form_Register extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setMethod('post');

        $this->addElements(
            [
                $this->getNameFirst(),
                $this->getNameLast(),
                $this->getEmail(),
                $this->getPassword(),
                $this->getPasswordConfrim(),
                $this->getSex(),
                $this->getDateBirth(),
                $this->getAddressStreet(),
                $this->getAddressStreetHn(),
                $this->getAddressStreetAn(),
                $this->getCityCode(),
                $this->getCityName(),
                $this->getSubmitButton(),
            ]
        );

    }
}
```

This is my registerAction in appropriate Controller:

```
public function registerAction()
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_Register();
        $this->view->form = $form;

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
                $values = $form->getValues();
                var_dump($values);die();
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know why isPost() method returns false. Any suggestions?

Comment: show your `indexAction` content in same controller

Comment: is empty. I didn't wrote code in this Action

Comment: and what action has rendered your form previously? or it wasn't rendered?

Comment: This form is first thing which I wrote. Code which I put here is almost all code from my project. Besides I render this form via `echo $this->form` in registerAction view.

Answer (score 1):

For good practice - change your logic as following below:

1. create view file with name `form.phtml` and the following exemplary content:

   ```
   <h2>Please sign up:</h2>
   <?php echo $this->form ?>
   ```
2. Modify your `RegisterController.php` in such way:

   ```
   class RegisterController extends Zend_Controller_Action
   {
       public function getForm()
       {
           // creating form
           $form = new Application_Form_Register();
           return $form;
       }

       public function indexAction()
       {
           // rendering form.phtml
           $this->view->form = $this->getForm();
           $this->render('form');
       }

       public function registerAction()
       {
           if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
               return $this->_forward('index');
           }
           $form = $this->getForm();
           if (!$form->isValid($_POST)) {
               // if form values aren't valid, output form again
               $this->form = $form;
               return $this->render('form');
           }

           $values = $form->getValues();
           //var_dump($values);die();
           // authentication...
       }
   }
   ```
3. At first `index` action must be called to show the register form to
   user. Also make sure that `submit` button on register form indicates
   to `register` action. I hope, you have added submit button in such
   way: `$form->addElement('submit', 'register', array('label' => 'Sign
   up'));`
4. Check results

Comment: I know that documentation show us this solution, but my question 'Is there any way to show and render form in one action?'. I know that is possible but how?

Comment: you may try to concentrate all logic within `indexAction` and change destination in submit button options: `$form->addElement('submit', 'index', array('label' => 'Sign
up'));`

Comment: Ok. I notice that your solution is working, but I don't know what is the different between
`$form->addElement('submit', 'index', array('label' => 'Sign up'));`
and
`$submitButton = new Zend_Form_Element_Button('submit');
        $submitButton->setLabel('Submit');
        $submitButton->setName('register');

        return $submitButton;`